# Navigation Links Not Working for Direct Page Access on Deployed React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Directly accessing the category page via pasting the link DOMAIN.COM/category is not working, but the home page at DOMAIN.COM is accessible without any errors. However, clicking on the category page link from the app's navbar works fine.

getting this on directly accessing DOMAIN.COM/category

404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND
ID: bom1::h4cpj-1683071927114-c9049f601df2